# Unable to add window in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send e-mai in background. I am using this library:[library](https://github.com/luongvo/GmailBackground) to achieve this, so i've created BroadcastReceiver with library code. But unfortunately i've got errror when i try to send e-mail:**Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?** I am trying to pass context from Activity, to BroadcastReceiver, but i think that context in Receiver is some kind of seperate only for this statement. Any advice to avoid this error?

**Manifest**

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".service.EmailReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="BackgroundProcessEmail" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

  
    String email=intent.getStringExtra("email");
    String password=intent.getStringExtra("password");


        String deviceModel = Build.MANUFACTURER
                + " " + Build.MODEL;

        assert email != null;
        assert password != null;
        BackgroundMail.newBuilder(context)
                .withUsername(email)
                .withPassword(password)
                .withSenderName("Full")
                .withMailTo("email")
                .withType(BackgroundMail.TYPE_PLAIN)
                .withSubject("Your device " + deviceModel +" achieved")
                .withBody("")
                .withSendingMessage("Sending email")
                .withOnSuccessCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnSendingCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFail(Exception e) {

                        Toasty.error(context, "E-mail sent error" + e.getMessage(), Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .send();

}
```